Why Eclipse with PyDev shows lines with Qt.LeftButton as an error with PySide6, even though the code still works
We are finally making a switch from pySide2 to pySide6 and this issue caught my attention. The code in question is pretty much anything that is using QCore.Qt library and this is one of examples:
if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
The same code with pySide2 didn't show any errors, but with the pySide6, it is not recognizing RightButton part. If code is changed to this instead:
if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
then Eclipse is happy and no error is presented in the IDE.
Yet, either version of the code is working just fine.
Looking into the definition of these enumerations, I can see this structure with the pySide6:
class Qt(Shiboken.Object):
    class MouseButton(enum.Flag):
        MouseButtonMask           = ...  # -1
        NoButton                  = ...  # 0x0
        LeftButton                = ...  # 0x1
        RightButton               = ...  # 0x2
        MiddleButton              = ...  # 0x4
        . . . 

This definition explains why there is an error there with the direct use of the enumeration, but not why the code still executes correctly both versions. As a matter of fact, I am perfectly fine with both version running, since I could leave the code as is. I don't have access to the pySide2 version of this library so I can't compare them, which would certainly help. But seeing all those errors in the IDE is annoying for sure.
Is there a way to understand better how this is working both ways, that could help me tweak Eclipse, so it doesn't show those lines as errors anymore?
Thanks!
The same code was showing no errors when running pySide2 in the same Eclipse IDE (the latest version 2024-09, with the PyDev 12.1.0). When I switched to pySide6, all these lines have shown as errors. Yet, code like this, executes just fine for both left and right click buttons:
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PySide6 Example")
        self.label = QLabel("Click anywhere", self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.label.setText("Left button clicked")
        elif event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
            self.label.setText("Right button clicked")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

but it displays this error message on the line where Qt.LeftButton is:
Undefined variable from import: LeftButton

My guess is that the enum "forgiveness mode" mentioned here: https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-for-python-release-6.4-is-finally-here  is done in a way so that PyDev is not able to see it. Why that is I have no idea but it seems we should switch to the new style enumerations anyway

So, the above mentioned forgiveness mode is allowing the code to work in both cases.
What is strange here is that after leaving my computer ON over the weekend with Eclipse running, it stopped showing those things as errors on Monday.
It is now obvious that this change was made to make things clearer and avoid possible wrong definitions used when they have identical name at the end. It is recommended to convert all these enums to the new full form and used them as such for any further development.
